# Identifying a load bearing wall in an a-frame?

Tags: structural, load-bearing

I want two remove two walls on the second floor a-frame that run perpendicular to the roofline. Some things I've noted:

- The sliding door when closed blocks the middle point / ridgeline
- The floor joists in the room run parallel to the wall, however the floor joists switch to perpendicular to the wall once it gets about a foot from the wall (ie. joists are perpendicular where the wall sits)

Thanks for any tips!

[image: yellow lines depict joists]

[image: same perspective/direction, but from inside wall on right]

[image: opposite side of the wall, looking back]

Edit: Update: Started pulling down the sliding door frame and drywall and unfortunately came across a beefy header above the door frame. Looks like this wall is load bearing and would need an engineer to redesign it if I want to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Where is the sliding door? Please provide a photo that shows its relationship to the ridgeline. Also, can you check the direction of the roof truss and let us know.

Comment: The sliding door is inside the wall to the left, in the first photo, behind the orange mountain photo. As for trusses, it's an a-frame and the ridgeline is perpendicular to that wall I want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assessment is this is a partition wall that does not carry the roof load, therefore it is removable without adverse effect. However, to be safe, you should invite a structural inspector or engineer to conduct an inspection and advise on the shoring requirement during modification.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and use the recip saw trick to see if it binds. But I'm most likely ok!

Comment: Be prudent, if the wall has been there for a long period, it might have some load in it as the roof and ceiling inevitably settle/deflect a small amount, so shoring is necessary during removal. Good luck.

Comment: I updated the post with a photo. From my uneducated opinion it looks like I'm SOL until I hire an engineer. At least I have a bigger door opening though and found a dead bird and a hole to the outside of the house on the right side...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the last photo shows a bearing wall directly under the roof truss. The roof load is passed to the vertical studs, beside the opening, to the structure below (another wall?), and the load on the opening is carried by the lintel beam to the sistered studs (posts) on the sides of the opening. Watch out, if you want to do anything about this wall.